# UWP focus control

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal

I have ListView with TextBoxes in universal windows 10 app. I want to write code: where user is editing any TextBox in Listiew and click enter key, I want to move focus to next TextBox in ListView (I want take the same action what happens where user click Tab key).

My question is: How to move focus programatically to the next listView element

Comment: When we press the Tab key, focus changes in the ListViewItem and won't move to next ListViewItem, so I'm not sure what you want to do. Do you want the Enter key acts like Tab key? Or when we press the Enter key, focus moves to the TextBox in next ListViewItem?

Comment: Do you want the Enter key acts like Tab key? Or when we press the Enter key, focus moves to the TextBox in next ListViewItem? - A booth.  For example: ListViewItem contains five TextBoxes, from the begining focus is on the first ListViewItem, on the first its TextBox. If I press EnterKey focus stays in current ListViewItem but moves to the next its TextBox. If the foxus is on the last TextBox, after EnterKey pressed, foxus is moved to next ListViewItem and its first TextBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume we have a model object like so:

```
public sealed class Item
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Let's fill a `ListView` with their strings:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}" Loaded="OnTextBoxLoaded" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <ListView.Items>
        <local:Item Value="One" />
        <local:Item Value="Two" />
        <local:Item Value="Three" />
        <local:Item Value="Four" />
    </ListView.Items>
</ListView>
```

The code-behind:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OnTextBoxLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;
        textBox.KeyUp += (o, args) =>
            {
                if (args.Key == VirtualKey.Enter)
                {
                    TextBox originalSource = (TextBox)args.OriginalSource;
                    int index = 0;
                    var items = listView.Items;
                    if (items != null)
                    {
                        foreach (Item item in items)
                        {
                            if (originalSource.DataContext == item)
                            {
                                break;
                            }

                            ++index;
                        }

                        index = (index + 1) % items.Count;
                        ListViewItem container = (ListViewItem)listView.ContainerFromIndex(index);
                        TextBox nextTextBox = FindVisualChild<TextBox>(container);
                        nextTextBox?.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
                    }
                }
            };
    }

    private static T FindVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject parent) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (parent != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); i++)
            {
                DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
                T candidate = child as T;
                if (candidate != null)
                {
                    return candidate;
                }

                T childOfChild = FindVisualChild<T>(child);
                if (childOfChild != null)
                {
                    return childOfChild;
                }
            }
        }

        return default(T);
    }
```

The tricky part is the mapping from the logical list (consisting of `Items`) to the visual list (`ListViewItem`s wrapping `TextBox`es).

Comment: Here is similiar topic on MSDN FORUM: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/b928da3c-a514-4069-bf11-0cd65d21f28c/how-to-move-focus-between-listviews-textboxes?forum=wpdevelop#c084c5af-5386-410e-8be1-c4842f25bcd4